# let function and array statement in a macro

Tags: arrays, macros, sas

I am new to SAS and Macros. I would like some help to understand what the following lines of code are doing:

```
%let numbercccats=201;

DATA &OUTDSN(KEEP=HICno CASE &prefix.CC1-&prefix.CC&numbercccats. ID) ERR;
SET TEMP1;
by ID;
length cc $4.;

cc=left(addxg);

RETAIN &prefix.CC1-&prefix.CC&numbercccats. 0 ; 
ARRAY C(&numbercccats.)  &prefix.CC1-&prefix.CC&numbercccats.;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could add tag about what language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added my explanation of what each line the SAS code does inline with the code below:

```
%let numbercccats=201;
/*Creates macro variable numbercccats with value 201*/

DATA &OUTDSN
/*Creates a SAS table; the table name will be te value in the macro variable OUTDSN*/

(KEEP=HICno CASE &prefix.CC1-&prefix.CC&numbercccats. ID) ERR;
/*Keep statement only keeps the column specified above*/
/*&prefix.CC1-&prefix.CC&numbercccats. is resolved to the value of the macro prefix concatinated with CC1-CC201*/
/*in other words you bring/keep 200 columns CC1,CC2,...CC201*/

SET TEMP1;
/*The input/source table is TEMP1 */

by ID;
/*Group by ID*/

length cc $4.;
/*Creates a new column named CC of length 4*/

cc=left(addxg);
/*Assigns the value of addxg to the new column cc, and removes leading spaces */

RETAIN &prefix.CC1-&prefix.CC&numbercccats. 0 ; 
/*for all the records with the same ID SAS won't change the value of the 200 columns CC1 to CC201*/

ARRAY C(&numbercccats.)  &prefix.CC1-&prefix.CC&numbercccats.;
/*An array called C of length 201 is created pointing to the 201 columns: CC1-CC201 */
```

Comment: SET TEMP1;
/*The new table created is named TEMP1*/
??????? with "set", the table is read not created.

Comment: Thank you @momo1644. Just to clarify this statement- ARRAY C(&numbercccats.)  &prefix.CC1-&prefix.CC&numbercccats.; Which one is the pointer array?  Is it the C(&numbercccats.) ?  I was not sure if this was a statement declaring 2 arrays or something else. You say that it is just a pointer array declaration? Please correct me if I am making a mistake in understanding this line of code.

Comment: The array name is C, the delcaration line translates to  C(201) CC1-CC201. So if you loop over the 201 array objects you are going through the 201 columns values.

Comment: This short SAS array tutorial will give you good understanding of how it works: http://www.stattutorials.com/SAS/Tutorial-SAS-ARRAYS.html

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I was not sure why it was done this way as I thought CC(20) would have taken you to the 20th index. However, you mention "column" which is basically supposed to be CC(1,20). Will go through the tutorial as I am trying to understand arrays more. Thanks a lot.